# Selecting Yes or No in putty command line prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, debian, putty

How do I choose Yes or No in putty command line question?

If I press Enter I assume that means Yes, but nothing happens if I press `N` (e.g., if I want to choose No)

[image]

Here's another similar situation where arrow keys or tabs don't work:

[image]

How do you select an option there?

Comment: What do arrow keys and tab do? Do they work?

Comment: @D.A nothing happens

Comment: what command are you running? I would like to recreate it, so that i can help

Comment: do a quick check, is _Allow terminal to specify ANSI colours_ checked in putty settings under _Window -> Colors_

Comment: @D.A yes it is checked. I am upgrading from Debian 7 to 8 (via Windows 7 Putty). It's all done now, I just pressed "enter" already since it's not a critical server and just went with the defaults without choosing any option. But I would still like to know how select options should I encounter this again in the future.

Comment: to be honest I have never encountered this issue before. I was assuming that the thing I asked you to check wasn't letting colors change, so that you couldn't see the option light up. Maybe it's something in the keyboard settings. I am gonna upvote and favourite the question. I would like to know the solution as well if someone knows.

Comment: If the arrow keys don't work properly, it probably means you don't have your `TERM` environment variable set correctly for the terminal emulation you have configured in Putty, so the server isn't recognizing the escape sequences they send.